# vim - non rectangular visual block

Tags: vim

Is there a way to select the second column in the following code,
which turns out to be non rectangular.

I tried "CTRLv 3jE" , but that doesn't work.

```
int var_one = 1;
int var_two = 2;
int var_three = 3;
int var_very_long = 4;
```

Comment: Was already answered, but what exactly do you want to do? Maybe there is another way if you tell what you pretend to do after selected.

Comment: @sidyll: i want to copy that column and then reproduce it in another location.
This was just an example, actually I needed this feature in writing scripts for my unit tests, which have lot of repetitive columns.

Answer (score 4):

You could use one of the Align plugins to align your column, select and copy it and afterwards undo the alignment (or leave it aligned)

Comment: Or instead of using a plugin for that, just select the four lines and type `:!column -t`. If you have `column`, of course.

Comment: The danger of this approach is if you start copying extra spaces. Should not be a problem though, depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I think the way to go is writing a custom function that
passes the task to awk. It could be done with some regex also, splitting each
line on spaces, but awk should be easier. Here is my first try:

```
function! ExtractColToRegister(reg, ...) range
    let input = join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline), "\n")
    if a:1 | let column = a:1
    else   | let column = 1 | endif
    exec "let @". a:reg . " = system(\"awk '{ print $" .
       \ column . " }'\", input)"
endfunction
```

You should have no trouble understanding it if you're already writing Vim
scripts :-) however let me know if some part of it is unclear, and if there is
something to improve as well.

Basically what the function does is saving a specific column to a register. If
you visually select the example code given in the question, and then:

```
:'<,'>call ExtractColToRegister("a", 2)
```

Register *a* will now contain:

```
var_one
var_two
var_three
var_very_long
```

And you can easily `"ap` somewhere else. Notice the column defaults to 1 if the
argument was omitted.

Creating a custom command "Column to Register" makes the process even nicier to
use outside of Vim scripts:

```
:command! -range -nargs=+ CTR <line1>,<line2>call ExtractColToRegister(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the CopyMatches function from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard

then select the lines and do something like

```
:'<,'>CopyMatches .*=
```